# Making custom class to behave like set

Tags: python, class, set

I try to make a class containing file names in a folder. But I want it to behave like set. Now I have this:

```
class Files():

    def __init__(self, in_dir):
        self.in_dir = in_dir
        self.files = set(map(os.path.basename, glob.glob(self.in_dir + "/*.txt")))

    def __add__(self, other):
        return self.files + other.files    

    def __or__(self, other):
        return self.files | other.files

    def __and__(self, other):
        return self.files & other.files

    def __xor__(self, other):
        return self.files ^ other.files
```

This work and I can do like this:

```
f1 = Files(inDir1)
f2 = Files(inDir2)

diff_files = f1 ^ f2 % this give files that are in f1 or f2 folder but not in both  folders
```

This is ok, but the problem is that `diff_files` is not instance of `Files`. How to change my class, to behave like set in python 3.x?

Comment: Any reason you're not using a `set` directly? I imagine there's more code you're not showing, but as it stands I would take the code you have in `__init__` and just make that a function that returns a set.

Comment: this is small example. I want Files to have custom functions, like delete files in self.files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, make `in_dir` argument optional:

```
def __init__(self, in_dir=None):
    if in_dir:
        self.in_dir = in_dir
        self.files = set(map(os.path.basename, glob.glob(self.in_dir + "/*.txt")))
```

Then, change the `__xor__()`:

```
def __xor__(self, other):
    instance = Files()
    instance.files = self.files ^ other.files
    return instance
```

Also, I don't see the reason to keep `in_dir` as an instance variable. You can simplify the `__init__()`:

```
def __init__(self, in_dir=None):
    if in_dir:
        self.files = set(map(os.path.basename, glob.glob(in_dir + "/*.txt")))
```

---

Alternatively, you can allow to initialize `Files` by passing a `files` set:

```
def __init__(self, in_dir=None, files=None):
    if in_dir:
        self.files = set(map(os.path.basename, glob.glob(in_dir + "/*.txt")))
    if files:
        self.files = files
```

Then, the `__xor__()` method would be even simpler:

```
def __xor__(self, other):
    return Files(files=self.files ^ other.files)
```

Comment: Thank you. I also think about extending set class, but dont know how. Is that better than like now?

Comment: @user3654650 I'm pretty much ok with the approach you currently have. But, take a look anyway: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/798442/what-is-the-correct-or-best-way-to-subclass-the-python-set-class-adding-a-new and http://www.itmaybeahack.com/book/python-2.6/html/p03/p03c04_extending.html. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "behaves like set" but I do understand that you want to return an instance of `Files` and not only the "diff", so for that:

change:

```
def __xor__(self, other):
        return self.files ^ other.files
```

to:

```
def __xor__(self, other):
        result = Files()
        result.in_dir = self.in_dir
        result.files = self.files ^ other.files
        return result
```