# Extend set to make custom set

Tags: python, subclass

This is new question because this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24113421/making-custom-class-to-behave-like-set).

I want to extend set to make custom set of file names in a folder:

```
class FilesSet(set):

    def __init__(self, in_dir = None):
        set.__init__(self, ())

        self.in_dir = ''
        self.files = set()        

        if in_dir:        
            self.in_dir = in_dir        
            self.files = set(map(os.path.basename, 
                             glob.glob(self.in_dir + "/*.txt")))


    def __contains__(self, item):
        return item in self.files

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.files)

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.files)
```

When I try it:

```
f1 = FilesSet(in_dir = inDir1)
f2 = FilesSet(in_dir = inDir2)

c1 = f1 | f2
c2 = f1 & f2

print(c1, c2)
```

c1 and c2 are empty. Why? Should I overwrite other methods from set? From [link](http://www.itmaybeahack.com/book/python-2.6/html/p03/p03c04_extending.html#collection-special-method-names-for-sets)  i think i only need to define **contains**, **len** and **iter**. Other methods like **or**(), **sub**(), **xor**() are for performance only, I understand.

Comment: If you want `|` and `&` to operate on your `files` attribute instead of the object itself, then yes, you need to override them.  There isn't much point in inheriting from `set` if you're going to create *another* set as an attribute and store all the data there.  Either make your own type that defines the operations you need, or inherit from `set` and store the data by directly manipulating `self`.

Comment: If all you want is input validation, then just extend `set` and wrap the `__init__()` function and other mutation functions like `add()` and `update()` to do the validation.