# Is there a python set deleting method that returns a value if the value you want to delete is not in the set?

Tags: python

Is there a deleting method for deleting an element of a set that takes a parameter to return if there is no element to delete that matches the parameter you gave it to delete?

So it would be something like set.discard(a,b) where a is the parameter that you want to delete and b is the parameter that gets returned if a is not found.

Comment: What should it return if it was found and removed?

Comment: The answer is a reassuring; no :) See: [``set()``](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set)

Comment: Python's set methods do not even return the removed element _if_ it was in the set; otherwise you could do `set.discard(a) or b`. But as it stands, you'll have to implement that method yourself.

Comment: If the item was successfully deleted nothing should be returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
def _discard(s, key, ret):
    try:
        s.remove(key)
    except KeyError:
        return ret
    return key    

s = set([1,2,3])
ret = "not found"

key = 4

print _discard(s, key, ret), s

key = 3

print _discard(s, key, ret), s
```

Comment: A better name is `pop(container, item, default=None)`

Comment: I agree, @J.F.Sebastian: @user4757074 can even implement it as a method of a subclass of `set` (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/798442/what-is-the-correct-or-best-way-to-subclass-the-python-set-class-adding-a-new).

Comment: btw, `set.pop` exists already but it has a strange behavior. I would use `dict.pop` as an example instead.

Answer (score 1):

Not built-in.
remove(elem)

> remove(elem)
>
> Remove element elem from the set. Raises KeyError if elem is not contained in the set.

Try to catch the exception in your own function maybe?
When exception caught return your element b.