# Is there a simple way to subclass python's set without redefining all operators?

Tags: python, python-3.x, subclassing

Is there a way to subclass `set`, with the binary operator returning the subclassed type, without redefining them ?

example :

```
class A(set):
    pass

a = A([1,2,3]) & A([1,2,4])


a.__class__ == A # it's False, and I would like it to be true without redefining all operators
```

**Note that this question : [What is the correct (or best) way to subclass the Python set class, adding a new instance variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/798442/what-is-the-correct-or-best-way-to-subclass-the-python-set-class-adding-a-new) is 10 years old and the provided answers are only relevant for python 2.x.
This is why I asked another question concerning python 3.x (especially, python ≥ 3.8).**

Comment: Note that this is NOT a duplicate. The linked question is 10 years old, and the provided answer are only relevant for python 2.x

Answer (score 3):

I believe the answer is "No".

As I skim the reference implementation it looks like all paths for  [`set_and()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/63d6f2623ef2aa90f51c6a928b96845b9b380d89/Objects/setobject.c#L1491) seem to ultimately return either `NULL` or the result of calling `make_new_set_basetype()`.

That method is [currently](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/63d6f2623ef2aa90f51c6a928b96845b9b380d89/Objects/setobject.c#L1097) implemented as:

```c
make_new_set_basetype(PyTypeObject *type, PyObject *iterable)
{
    if (type != &PySet_Type && type != &PyFrozenSet_Type) {
        if (PyType_IsSubtype(type, &PySet_Type))
            type = &PySet_Type;
        else
            type = &PyFrozenSet_Type;
    }
    return make_new_set(type, iterable);
}
```

Thus without overriding `__and__()` in your sub-class, what you are going to get back is a `set()` or a `frozenset()`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you do need to redefine the set methods, but only the ones that return `set` object, which is only 13 method, and all of it is boilerplate code.

Here is an example:

```
class ASet(set):
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'ASet({set(self)})'

    def __and__(self, other):
        return self.__class__(super().__and__(other))

    def __or__(self, other):
        return self.__class__(super().__or__(other))

    def __rand__(self, other):
        return self.__class__(super().__rand__(other))

    def __ror__(self, other):
        return self.__class__(super().__ror__(other))

    def __rsub__(self, other):
        return self.__class__(super().__rsub__(other))

    def __rxor__(self, other):
        return self.__class__(super().__rxor__(other))

    def __sub__(self, other):
        return self.__class__(super().__sub__(other))

    def __xor__(self, other):
        return self.__class__(super().__xor__(other))

    def copy(self, other):
        return self.__class__(super().copy(other))

    def difference(self, other):
        return self.__class__(super().difference(other))

    def intersection(self, other):
        return self.__class__(super().intersection(other))

    def symmetric_difference(self, other):
        return self.__class__(super().symmetric_difference(other))

    def union(self, other):
        return self.__class__(super().union(other))
```

Comment: note that since `__and__` is an alias of `intersection` (and same for other methods), we can do `intersection = __and__` that makes it a tiny bit less